# Combobox.SelectedIndex não retorna o item no Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Estou com um programa em windows forms e preciso selecionar o item em um combo box para que o usuário possa editar o registro, porém, ele recebe o valor, acha o index mas não retorna o selecionado na tela.
segue o código:

```
private void PreencherCbox(List<Natureza> lista)
    {
        List<CboxModel> model = new List<CboxModel>();

        CboxModel p = new CboxModel();

        p.Text = "Selecione uma natureza";
        p.Value = "0";

        model.Add(p);

        foreach (Natureza n in lista)
        {
            CboxModel m = new CboxModel();
            m.Text = n.Descricao;
            m.Value = n.Id.ToString();

            model.Add(m);
        }

        this.CboxNatureza.DataSource = model;
        CboxNatureza.DisplayMember = "Text";
        CboxNatureza.ValueMember = "Value";
    }
```

e na hora de receber o valor e selecionar:

```
this.CboxNatureza.SelectedIndex = CboxNatureza.FindStringExact(e.Natureza.Descricao);
```

tenho outro trecho de código que está igual, mas funciona. Ajuda aê! =D

Comment: O correto não seria você consultar o valor setado para `this.CboxNatureza.SelectedValue`?

Comment: Já tentei também e não consegui. No meu outro form eu faço dessa mesma maneira como mostrei acima e funciona perfeitamente...

Answer (score 0):

Você esta criando um modelo (`CboxModel`), só para adicionar um simples texto (Selecione uma natureza), já tentou usar uma `Label` para ilustrar tal texto?

Experimente fazer assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> - A propriedade `.SelectedIndex` recebendo -1, deixa o campo de texto vazio.
> - Utilize a propriedade `.SelectedValue` para o retorno do item, mais note que a propriedade `.ValueMember` foi alimentada com o campo ´ID´
>     da classe `Natureza` que encontra-se na `List<>`, sendo assim vai
>     retorna um número.
> - O tipo de retorno do `.SelectedValue` é um `object`, então dependendo do uso atente-se ao tratamento.

Logo seu código ficaria assim:

```
//-->Seu Método
private void PreencherCbox(List<Natureza> lista){
   this.CboxNatureza.DataSource = lista;
   CboxNatureza.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
   CboxNatureza.ValueMember = "Id";
   CboxNatureza.SelectedIndex = -1;       
}
```

Comment: Rapaz, entendi o que você explicou, porém, esse Form que estou criando, ele tem um construtor que recebe um Id. Depois que recebe esse Id, eu retorno todo o registro para esse form e aí sim que vem a necessidade de já deixar selecionado no dropdown a natureza correspondente desse registro.. Não preciso de um evento novo para isso.. não sei se me expressei bem

Comment: @IvoJúnior pelo que você comentou agora, entendi que vc está desenvolvendo um `Form` para Edição de alguma coisa e no carregamento desse `Form` você recebe um ID que define o `Item(qualquer coisa)` que estará sendo Editado. Esse Item no caso já possui Natureza e vc não esta conseguindo carregá-la na `ComboBox`. É isso?

Comment: Correto! Tudo já está ok, exceto a seleção da natureza no combobox

Comment: Utilize o método da maneira como está agora. Outra coisa, caso não resolva, mostre um print do que esta acontecendo (como a combobox esta reagindo no Load()).

Comment: `this.CboxNatureza.SelectedIndex = CboxNatureza.FindStringExact(en.Natureza.Descricao); `
Esse código retorna o índice 2, que é a posição do item correspondente a essa natureza que deve aparecer selecionada no form, porém, na exibição, ele continua exibindo o primeiro item do dropdown.

Comment: Realmente era para estar funcionando pois `.FIndStringExact()` retorna um `int` que corresponde ao índice. O que vem na sequencia  depois dessa atribuição? Se vem algo, já verificou se algum método está provocando essa alteração no `.SelectedIndex` da `CboxNatureza` ?

Comment: Essa é a última linha. Não tem mais nada...